# ClassNotFoundException(mysql-connector ,jdbc)

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea

I've added the mysql-connector.jar into my project in Intellij IDEA through `File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> Dependences -> '+'(JARS or directories) -> ok` . It should work.

```
    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,NAME,PASSWD);
```

When I run this project, it throwed an exception that says *classnotfound*…

my project structures :

```
>myproject<br/>
--.gradle<br/>
--.idea<br/>
--build<br/>
--src<br/>
build.gradle<br/>
settings.gradle<br/>
>\>External Librares<br/>
mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar<br/>
<1.8><br/>
Gradle:junit:junit:4.12<br/>
Gradle:org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3<br/>
```

Comment: Please check your run classpath. Is mysql-connector.jar existed there?

Comment: could u show me how to check my run classpath? where am i supposed to check it out

Comment: Run classpath shoud be shown in the output panel when you run application.